# Calculate the formula, and moles

Tags: stoichiometry, molecules, mole

> If $\ce{1.84\times10^{-4}}$ moles of element A was completely reacted with element B to create $\ce{1.231\times 10^19}$ molecules of $\ce{(A3B2)_x}$ a hypothetical compound, what is the value of x?

I tried this:

---

$\pu{1 mol} = 6.02 \times 10^{23} ~\pu{molecules}$

$y~\pu{mol} = 1.231 \times 10^{19} ~\pu{molecules}$

$y = \pu{2.0449 \times 10^-5 mol}$

---

$\ce{(A_3B_2)_x} : 1.84\times10^{-4}+ {2\over 3}(1.84\times10^{-4})=3.067\times10^{-4}$

So it produces $3.067\times10^{-4}$ mol of the compound

---

and, $3.067 \times 10^{-4}~\pu{mol} \div 2.0449 \times 10^{-5}~\pu{mol} = 15$

And since 1 compound has 5 atoms, $15 \div 5 =3$

Therefore, $x$ is 3

---

I am not sure if I did this question correctly. Even if I did, is there a more efficient and organized way of solving this problem?

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you did below the first horizontal line? ("1 mol = 6.02×1023 molecules;x mol =1.231×1019 molecules;x = 2.0449×10−5 mol") what are you trying to do by that?

Comment: well, 1.84×10−4 is in moles, while  1.231×1019  is the actual number of molecules. So I'm trying to convert number molecules into moles

Comment: @didgocks use different variables. “x mol = $\mathrm{1.231 x 10^{19}}$ and we also have $\ce{(A3B2)_x}$ “.

Answer (score 0):

At first you said that $x = \pu{2.0449\times10^−5 mol}$ and then later said $x=3$. It is clearly wrong even without going into the maths!

That said, I believe you are confusing the stoichiometry of the compound with the number of moles of the compound produced. The $x$ in $\ce{(A3B2)_x}$ is a *part of the chemical formula* for that compound, and **not** the *moles of $\ce{(A3B2)}$ produced*.

For example, $\ce{AlCl3}$ usually exists as a *dimer* in gas phase, so we write it as $\ce{Al2Cl6}$ or simply $\ce{(AlCl3)2}$ for clarity. You should hence realize that the **$x$ in $\ce{(A3B2)_x}$ represents the number of $\ce{A3B2}$ molecules that have *polymerized* together to form a *single* *molecule***. And the question states that $\pu{1.231\times10^19}$ of such *molecules* was produced.

With the conceptual clarity attained, we'll now solve the numerical. Note that the question says that all the moles of elemental A were obtained in the compound. This implies:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{moles of A in the compound} &= \text{original moles of elemental A}\\
\implies 3x\times(\text{moles of compound }\ce{A3B2})&=1.84\times10^{-4}
\end{align}
$$

Solving this, you'll get approximately $x=3$, which is the expected answer.